# How to drag visible areas of SVG

Tags: html, jquery-ui, svg

Currently, I have a puzzle, consisting of several SVGs. I can use `img` tags and make them draggable using jQuery UI.

The problem is that each one acts as a rectangle, and many are very much not rectangular.

I want to drag only when over the painted part of the SVG.

I've tried `object`, but that doesn't drag at all.

What is the best way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

You could use inline svg instead of `img`, like in this [example](http://jeremie.patonnier.net/experiences/svg/inline/puzzle.en.xhtml).

If you want to use rectangular images as the source, note that they may be clipped to any irregular shape using the `clip-path` property. That will affect whether some part is to be considered "transparent" to mouse events.